# Is there a function similar to qsort() to be used in kernel space?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, qsort

I'm writing a loadable kernel module and I need to use the function `qsort()` which apparently cannot be used in kernel space.

Is there a function that I can use that has a similar functionality ?

(Kernel version 3.5.0)

Comment: Quicksort is not an appropriate algorithm for kernel code--its performance is too unpredictable. Use a nice reliable heapsort.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: `qsort()` isn't required to use Quicksort.

Comment: True, but it often does. I would still roll my own for a kernel module.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The linux kernel includes an implementation of heapsort which performs similar to quicksort. The kernel developers recommend heapsort over quicksort (within the kernel) and give the following rationale:

> Sorting time [of heapsort] is O(n log n) both on average and worst-case. While
>   qsort is about 20% faster on average, it suffers from exploitable
>   O(n*n) worst-case behavior and extra memory requirements that make
>   it less suitable for kernel use.

### Header

```
#include <linux/sort.h>
```

### Prototype

```
void sort(
    void *base, size_t num, size_t size,
    int (*cmp_func)(const void *, const void *),
    void (*swap_func)(void *, void *, int size));
```

### Usage

```
static int compare(const void *lhs, const void *rhs) {
    int lhs_integer = *(const int *)(lhs);
    int rhs_integer = *(const int *)(rhs);

    if (lhs_integer < rhs_integer) return -1;
    if (lhs_integer > rhs_integer) return 1;
    return 0;
}

void example() {
    int values[1024] = {...};
    sort(values, 1024, sizeof(int), &compare, NULL);
}
```

Comment: The `qsort` function isn't necessarily implemented with the Quicksort algorithm. The language standard just says that it sorts. A conforming, but perverse, implementation could even use Bubblesort. (Yes, the name `qsort` is an abbreviation of "Quicksort", but there's no requirement that it be implemented that way.)

Answer (score 5):

That's a good question. The function`sort()` in [lib/sort.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8a72f3820c4d14b27ad5336aed00063a7a7f1bef/lib/sort.c) does the job, but it's a heap sort, you can learn more about this choice in `lib/sort.c`

Comment: This doesn't have enough information to constitute a good answer.  How did you determine there aren't any equivalents?

Comment: I found a qsort implementation in some guy's lib/qsort.c folder in his linux kernel repo, but I can't find it in Torvald's repo. I'll grep his repo for qsort, though.